# is there any way to to check whether the value present in row for multiple columns

Tags: java

I have a String variable `abc` . Now I would like to check whether the value of `abc` is present in a searched row form sql (table X ) for multiple COLUMNS.

So if (`abc`) is present in `COLUMN01 ,COLUMN02, ....COLUMN50`. Let's say flag `PRESENT` is set.

I have this kind of requirement. It can be accomplished by hard coding and checking all the 50 columns one by one.

Is there any other way?

Comment: There's no reason to shout (upper case is considered shouting). Just ask normally and show what you've been trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a really clever way but you could just iterate over all the columns in the result set (should be doable without knowing how many there are) and check them as you iterate.

Something like this:

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
for( int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); ++i ) {
  //check the type of the column, you might want to check more types than VARCHAR
  if( meta.getColumnType( i ) == VARCHAR ) {
    //check for the value "abc"
    if( "abc".equals( resultSet.getString( i ) ) ) {
      //found it
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is optimal solution i think . But this checks all the columns . I need to check only 50 sequential columns  only('ABC01 to ABC50').

Comment: @AbhishekBhandari if you know the columns are named `ABC01` to `ABC50` you can skip the metadata checks, iterate from 1 to 50 and access the columns by name (which is constructed by concatenating `ABC` and the index as a 2-digit number - I'll leave that as an exercise for your google skills :) ).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [SQL WHERE clause](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-WHERE.asp) with [SQL IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp). Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720204/search-a-resultset-for-a-specific-value-method)

Comment: SANDEEP , COULD YOU PLEASE ELABORATE .I BELIEVE YOU GOT THE QUESTION WELL .

Comment: I dont think this is what he is asking. He wants to search all columns without having to actually do a WHERE clause for all columns

Comment: You got the Question wrong sandeep . If i use WHERE here I have to check all the 50 columns again (A kind of hard coding again). I am talking about some solution from Reflection class of java after we retrieve value from SQl .

Comment: Matt got it right  . And i want to do it in java . After i have all the columns value in a Dto

Answer (score 0):

The SQL "[IN](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-IN.asp)" clause might be useful to you:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE "abc" IN (COLUMN01, COLUMN02, COLUMN03, ... COLUMN50)
```

You can use it in the selected fields rather than the WHERE clause if you want a "present" flag:

```
SELECT *, ("abc" IN (COLUMN01, COLUMN02, COLUMN03, ... COLUMN50)) AS present FROM ... WHERE ...
```

There's no direct way to search horizontally so you still need to list all the columns, but the abc variable only needs to be subbed in once.

If that's not what you want please be more detailed.

Comment: Yes almost to the solution. That is what i have to adopt if found no other alternatives . But in fact I am trying to do it in java . First i will get the records form 'DB' in a 'DTO list' . Then i dont know whether i can or not buy i will try to do it with java reflection. :)

Answer (score 0):

For each row, iterate through all the coloumns, and set the flag false, in case one turns out not equal.

```
flag=true;

while (rs.next()) {

       for(int 1=1;i<=50;i++)
           {
             if(!rs.getString(i).equals(abc)){ flag=false;break; }

           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Thomas . I implemented the idea with reflection as that was i intending to do ! nice stuffs Java Reflection .

```
   String ColumnPrefix = "Abc";
    SomeDto kals = new SomeDto ();
    kals = (SomeDto)DbResult

     Class klsss = kals.getClass();
    Method[] method = klsss.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
        Method m= method[i];
        if (m.getName().toString().startsWith("get".concat(ColumnPrefix))) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                String returnValue = (String) m.invoke(kals, null);
                if ("test me".equals(returnValue)) {
                    System.out.println("this is working");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Illegal argument");
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                System.out.println("Illegal IllegalAccessException Ecxeption");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                System.out.println("Illegal InvocationTargetException Ecxeption");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }'
```